# Hash Map using hash() Method

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance, hashmap

Based on some tutorial, I've applied a `HashMap` class, and just used a `__get_hash_mod_size()` method,

```
def __get_hash_mod_size(self, key):
    hash_key_var = hash(key+str(self.hahsmap_size*0.01))
    return hash_key_var % self.hahsmap_size
```

and everything seems to be working OK, I'm not sure though, and I'd like to see some views to improve it or if there might be any problem or edge cases?

#### HashMap

```
class HashMap():
    def __init__(self):
        self.hahsmap_size = 32
        self.hashmap_data = [None] * self.hahsmap_size

    def __get_hash_mod_size(self, key):
        hash_key_var = hash(key+str(self.hahsmap_size*0.01))
        return hash_key_var % self.hahsmap_size

    def set_key_value(self, key, value):
        key_var = self.__get_hash_mod_size(key)
        key_value_list = [key, value]

        if self.hashmap_data[key_var] is None:
            self.hashmap_data[key_var] = list([key_value_list])
            return True
        else:
            for pair in self.hashmap_data[key_var]:
                print(pair)
                if pair[0] == key:
                    pair[1] = value
                    return True
            self.hashmap_data[key_var].append(key_value_list)
            return True

    def get_key(self, key):
        key_var = self.__get_hash_mod_size(key)
        if self.hashmap_data[key_var] is not None:
            for pair in self.hashmap_data[key_var]:
                if pair[0] == key:
                    return pair[1]
            return None
    
    def remove_key(self, key):
        key_var = self.__get_hash_mod_size(key)

        if self.hashmap_data[key_var] is not None:
            return False
        for i in range(len(self.hashmap_data[key_var])):
            if self.hashmap_data[key_var][i][0] == key:
                self.hashmap_data[key_var].pop(i)
                return True
    def print_hashmap(self):
        for item in self.hashmap_data:
            if item is not None:
                print(item)


hm = HashMap()
hm.set_key_value('A', '1')
hm.set_key_value('A', '2')
hm.set_key_value('B', '1')
hm.set_key_value('A', '3')
hm.set_key_value('A', '4')
hm.set_key_value('C', '1')
hm.set_key_value('D', '1')
hm.set_key_value('E', '1')
hm.set_key_value('E', '2')
hm.remove_key('A')
hm.remove_key('B')
hm.remove_key('B')
hm.print_hashmap()
```

Comment: "and everything seems to be working OK, I'm not sure though, and I'd like to see some views to improve it or if there might be any problem or edge cases?" Frankly, that seems better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of StackOverflow

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this questions asks for opinions on working code, and thus should belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am bugged that `hahsmap_size` is misspelled.  Otherwise this seems to be a working implementation of what Python natively provides as a dictionary.

That is, this code:

```
hm = HashMap()
hm.set_key_value('A', '1')
hm.set_key_value('A', '2')
hm.set_key_value('B', '1')
hm.set_key_value('A', '3')
hm.set_key_value('A', '4')
hm.set_key_value('C', '1')
hm.set_key_value('D', '1')
hm.set_key_value('E', '1')
hm.set_key_value('E', '2')
hm.remove_key('A')
hm.remove_key('B')
hm.remove_key('B')
hm.print_hashmap()
```

is equivalent to but slower than this:

```
hm = {}
hm['A'] = '1'
hm['A'] = '2'
hm['B'] = '1'
hm['A'] = '3'
hm['A'] = '4'
hm['C'] = '1'
hm['D'] = '1'
hm['E'] = '1'
hm['E'] = '2'
hm.pop('A', None)
hm.pop('B', None)
hm.pop('B', None)
print(hm)
```

Comment: I suspect he knows that. He's doing this as an exercise to implement it himself.